# Amazon S3 REST API Malformed XML Error on PutBucketLifeCycle

Tags: xml, rest, amazon-web-services

I am trying to do a PUT request via the REST API to establish a lifecycle rule as described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTlifecycle.html

But even when I PUT the exact same XML Data as in Example 1, I get a 'Malformed XML Error'. Also Content-Length and MD5 of the request in this example seem not to be valid as I calculate different values.

My put is:

```
PUT https://myBucket.s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/?lifecycle
Content-length: 397
Content-MD5: Or7bcOqR6tcsifiqQpq1tw==
… (Signature headers etc.)

<LifecycleConfiguration>
  <Rule>
    <ID>id1</ID>
    <Prefix>documents/</Prefix>
    <Status>Enabled</Status>
    <Transition>
      <Days>30</Days>
      <StorageClass>GLACIER</StorageClass>
    </Transition>
  </Rule>
  <Rule>
    <ID>id2</ID>
    <Prefix>logs/</Prefix>
    <Status>Enabled</Status>
    <Expiration>
      <Days>365</Days>
    </Expiration>
  </Rule>
</LifecycleConfiguration>
```

and has a Content-Length of *397* and a MD5 of *Or7bcOqR6tcsifiqQpq1tw==*

I get this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>MalformedXML</Code>
  <Message>The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema</Message>    
  <RequestId>FC82F477B48DF40D</RequestId>    
   <HostId>5nJaHpypZQ/boh5fmtYWcvozeRO/OYIfuvYRXj2Un56tWPP2sj2jpazl0Xyl09Ic4s2lxh0l+C8=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Any help on this is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For others finding this issue from search engines:

`<Prefix></Prefix>` – an empty prefix is required for this call to work as "for whole bucket".

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. The endpoint URL was wrong as the parameters got skipped by my code when creating a PUT request.

If you get an XML Malformed error make sure your Endpoint URL is correct.